# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' при использовании webpack devserver

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

При использовании webpack dev sever столкнулся со следующей проблемой, сразу после запуска получаю следующие ошибки:

```
> webpack-dev-server --open

i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from D:\FRONT\project
× ｢wdm｣: asset main.js 649 bytes [emitted] (name: main)

ERROR in main
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in 'D:\FRONT\project'

ERROR in main
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in 'D:\FRONT\project'

webpack 5.11.0 compiled with 2 errors in 94 ms
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

Проект лежим в папке project в ней нахоядтся папки dev (с исходными файлами) и целевая build. Ниже привожу код фала webpack.config.js.

```
const path = require(`path`);

module.exports = {
    mode: `development`,
    entry: `./dev/app/main.js`,
    output: {
        filename: `bundle.js`,
        path: path.join(__dirname, `build/app/`)
    },
    devtool: `source-map`,
    devServer:{
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, `build/app/`),
        watchContentBase: true
    }
};
```

Если запускать не Dev server, а просто сборку через webpack, то все выполняется корректно, файл-бандл формируется и попадает в папку назначения. Но при запуске дев сервера падают указанные ранее ошибки и окрыватеся страница, которую привожу на скриншоте ниже. Если в этой странице открыть нужную папку build/app/, то сайт запускает.

[image: Страница с файлами проекта]

Подскажите пожалуйста, что делаю не так? Почему вебпак не видит нужные файлы и пытается искать какой-то './src', который я нигде не указывал?

Заранее очень благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: А внутри исходного кода точно нигде нет импорта ./src?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потратил на поиски несколько дней, в итоге нашел решение здесь - https://cyishere.medium.com/error-cannot-find-module-webpack-cli-bin-config-yargs-6d704533062a

Answer (score 0):

У меня сейчас была проблема такая - при запуске `npx webpack`.

В корневой папке лежали все файлы, я изменил импорт в html:
было `src="script.js"`
сделал `src="src/script.js"`
и добавил в корне папку `src` в которую и переместил этот скрипт.

Чудесным образом всё заработало без ошибки. Вдруг кому поможет.